# Why is Apache with mod_wsgi + mod_php causing segmentation fault?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-wsgi, mac-osx

I'm using Macports on OS X 10.6 to manage Apache, PHP, and Python.  I've never had any problems and the setup works great.  However, when I add mod_wsgi to the mix Apache immediately crashes with a segmentation fault.  Here's what's installed via macports:

- apache2 @2.2.17_0+preforkmpm
- php5 @5.3.3_1+apache2+pear
- python27 @2.7.1_0
- mod_wsgi @3.2_0+python27

After installing mod_wsgi, adding it to httpd.conf, and restarting apache, it seg faults every time.  I do not have mod_python installed.  If I remove mod_php by commenting it out of httpd.conf, apache runs fine.  So it's clearly the mix of mod_wsgi and mod_php that's causing a crash.  Any ideas on what's wrong? How can I avoid the seg fault when both are running together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common cause is multiple different versions of a library being used by different modules. Use `otool -L` against the various dynamic libraries to see which have the conflict, then rebuild appropriately.

Comment: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0); /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1); /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.42.0)
Is there anything wrong here?  I have no idea what it should look like.

Comment: Thanks!  Compared the versions for libraries that the modules had in common.  Found one that differed, recompiled PHP, and all is well.